# MVVM: Model inside another Model

Tags: c#, mvvm, model, mvvmcross

I have a model called Events and a Model called Persons. Am I fine, when I include an ObservableCollection of the type Persons in the Event Model? Is this right MVVM? Do I need everywhere an NotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds fine to me.  Have both your Event model and Person model implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

The front end can then be notified when the ObservableCollection changes and also be notified when properties on the Event and Person models change.

Comment: I use mvvmcross, and it looks like that you normaly just call a provided method in the viewmodel. Its even not available in a classic model

Comment: I haven't used mvvmcross, but it looks like if your Event and Person "viewmodels" inherit from the MvxViewModel base class, you use the inherited RaisePropertyChanged method to notify the frontend when a property changes value.  Using an ObservableCollection to notify the frontend when a collection of objects changes is independent of this but they should be able to work together without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Will you display in the Events view the list of persons? if that is true then you are correct, that is MVVVM, remember the ViewModels stands between your Models and your Views, and need to satisfy the data and functional requirements of your View.